# gawk: Print header row before selecting rows based on field content

Tags: awk

I have large .csv files of environmental permit holders and I want to extract rows for only a certain permit type, but include the header row, too. My current script:

```
BEGIN { FS = OFS = ","
  NR == 1; print $0 }
  $7 ~ /"GEN12Z"/ { print $0 }
```

This prints a blank line then all rows where $7 matches the pattern string. I've tried other syntax to identify the first row and add it before the extracted rows but all fail to do that. A clue stick is needed.

TIA,

Rich

Comment: Show use sample input & expected output in a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example.](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Regarding "I've tried other syntax" - when trying to learn a new tool, don't just try putting bits and pieces of language constructs together in various ways to see what happens, read a **little** bit about the language and google a couple of examples, there are a ton out there, including thousands on this forum, Or even ask ChatGPT - that'd probably give you something syntactically correct which you could then debug to make functional.

Comment: Just googling your subject line, https://www.google.com/search?q=awk+Print+header+row+before+selecting+rows+based+on+field+content, finds a ton of scripts that would be a good starting point for you.

Comment: Think about your braces around the `BEGIN` block. You have included the test of `NR==1` in the `BEGIN` block. As a first hint, try: `BEGIN { FS = OFS = "," }` (note closing `}`) then `NR == 1 {print $0; next }` will get you closer.

Answer (score 2):

The blank line is coming from the `print $0` in the `BEGIN` block; the issue here is the `BEGIN` block is processed before any input lines are processed which means `$0` is undefined (aka empty) hence the `print $0` generates a blank line.

From the description it sounds like OP wants to print the first line of the file hence the code snippet `NR == 1; print $0`, but there are a couple issues here:

- this code snippet needs to be moved out of the `BEGIN` block so that it can be applied against the input lines
- `NR==1;` is a standalone comparison and because of the trailing `;` doesn't actually trigger the `print $0`; removing the `;` then leaves us with a syntax error

Fixing OP's code to what I think is desired:

```
$ cat test.awk
BEGIN { FS = OFS = "," }
  NR == 1         { print $0 }
  $7 ~ /"GEN12Z"/ { print $0 }
```

Sample data file:

```
$ cat dat.csv
header row
1,2,3,4,5,6,"GEN001",123
1,2,3,4,5,6,"GEN12Z",ABC
1,2,3,4,5,6,"GEN001",123
1,2,3,4,5,6,"GEN12Z",DEF
```

Testing the new code:

```
$ awk -f test.awk dat.csv
header row
1,2,3,4,5,6,"GEN12Z",ABC
1,2,3,4,5,6,"GEN12Z",DEF
```

Since `print $0` is the default action for a successful comparison we could also use any of the following to generate the same output:

```
BEGIN { FS = OFS = "," }
  NR == 1
  $7 ~ /"GEN12Z"/

------------------

BEGIN { FS = OFS = "," }
  NR == 1 || $7 ~ /"GEN12Z"/

------------------

BEGIN { FS = OFS = "," }
  NR == 1; $7 ~ /"GEN12Z"/
```